# Как правильно использовать rewrite в Nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть урлы

```
xxx.ru/sd/step-01
xxx.ru/sd/step-02
```

Есть файлы на сервере

```
/home/1.php
/home/2.php
```

Как с помощью `rewrite` задать правильный роутинг? 
Пробовал так, но выдает 404

```
rewrite  ^/sd/step-([0-9]) $1.php;
```

Comment: Читайте в логах nginx, почему получилось 404

Comment: А вообще очевидно, что регулярка `([0-9])` соответствует одной цифре, а не двум

Comment: @andreymal но у меня оно на любом урле такое

Comment: до 10 не успел дойти)

Comment: `rewrite  ^/sd/step-([0-9])([0-9]?) /home/$2.php;`

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica неа. 404

Comment: @Radzhab логи покажите nginx'а.

Comment: [28/Dec/2019:17:20:55 +0000] "GET /sd/step-01 HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"